# SharedPreferences are not stored after restarting app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

maybe someone experienced the same problem with Android 8.
I wrote an application for an older Android version ( Android 6 and 7 ).
Now, after having updated my mobile phone to Android 8 it seems as if SharedPreferences are not stored anymore although my application was working fine for a long time with older Android versions.

As long as I save my settings for the current session everything is working fine but as soon as I restart my application all the settings seem to be lost.

I also checked my security settings in Android but they seem to be fine, too.

I have not changed any line of code in my app so I think it has something to do with Android itself.

Did somebody experience the same problem or maybe he/she knows how to solve the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Post your code. Nobody can help you like this and your question will get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you write your questions you always find the answer.

The problem lies within the security settings for SharedPreferences: MODE_WORLD_READABLE is not allowed anymore or it was deprecated and now it was deleted.